# Owl Carousel. Кастомные кнопки

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Как можно поставить в Owl Carousel свою иконку на след и пред кнопки? Делаю background-image, но не помогает. Там background-color используется

Answer (score 1):

Заведите отдельные стили для этих кнопок:

```
.btn.next {background: url('путь к картинке') no-repeat;} 
.btn.prev {background: url('путь к картинке') no-repeat;}
```

которые отменят `background-color` у стиля `.btn`.

Ну и `.btn.next:hover, .btn.next:focus, .btn.prev:hover, .btn.prev:focus`, если нужен эффект при наведении.

Просто `background-color`, по сравнению с `background-image`, в данном случае приоритетнее.